# Преобразование текста с разделителями в yaml

Tags: golang, инспекция-кода

Написал [функцию](https://github.com/udonetsm/yamlformat) парсинга обычного текста с разделителями в yaml формат

```
package yamlformat

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

/* This function converts simple text with control simbool to yaml format <key: "value"> */
func ParseStringToYamlFormat(str []byte, controlline, controlstring string) [][]byte {
    var key, value, newline string
    lines := strings.Split(string(str), controlline)
    var parsed_lines [][]byte
    for _, line := range lines {
        if !strings.Contains(line, controlstring) {
            continue
        }
        letters := strings.Split(line, "")
        lenletters := len(letters)
        for letter_indx := 0; letter_indx < lenletters; letter_indx++ {
            if letters[letter_indx] == controlstring {
                for val_inx := letter_indx + 1; val_inx < lenletters; val_inx++ {
                    value += letters[val_inx]
                }
                for key_indx := 0; key_indx < letter_indx; key_indx++ {
                    key += letters[key_indx]
                }
                newline = fmt.Sprintf(`%s: "%s" `, strings.TrimSpace(key), strings.TrimSpace(value))
                key, value = "", ""
            }
        }
        parsed_lines = append(parsed_lines, []byte(newline))
        newline = ""
    }
    return parsed_lines
}
```

Кто-то может проанализировать и сказать является ли это приемлемым алгоритмом и что можно улучшить? Буду премного благодарен)

Comment: а зачем нужен цикл по символам, если ты можешь сразу вызвать `split` по нужному символу и получить две твои искомые строки?

Comment: @Grundy я уже, честно говоря, не помню почему я его добавил. Изначальный код был такой как вы говорите, но потом, при определенном формате текста, функция то ли не работала вообще то ли работала некорректно. Возможно с пробелами тогда не дружила функция или с несколькими парами в строке. Не помню уже. Суть в том, что я пробовал без этого цикла и чтото там не срасталось, не могу уже вспомнить что именно((